# Reverse order of operations for OnClick and OnClientClick?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have some simple javascript that I'd like to run when a button is clicked, but I also want some postback action to occur on the server.  The logical code for this looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" OnClientClick="UpdateParent();" OnClick="btnOK_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="window.close();" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateParent()
    {
    window.opener.document.location.reload(true); // or should we postback instead?
    window.close();     
    }
</script>
```

Basically, a popup window should refresh its parent and then close itself.  However... if I call window.close(), the postback does not occur and the button handler is not called.  But obviously OnClientClick is called before the postback happens.  Am I going to have to emit this javascript in the button handler and run it when the page loads after postback?  If so, what is the **proper** way to do this these days for ASP.NET 2.0?

It's a shame that the code above doesn't work as it's elegantly simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the postback before closing the window. Also you want to do the postback before refreshing the parent window, as I guess that the reason to refresh the window is to display the information that you are about to save.

Use the `RegisterStartupScript` in the `ClientScript` object to run the code after postback:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "window.opener.location.reload(true);window.close();", true);
```

However, if the parent page is a result of a postback, this would cause a dialog window in the browser informing the user that a post request is needed to reload the page. To avoid this you would have to do something like calling a function in the parent page that could do a postback to update the page.

Comment: Ended up doing exactly this.  Added a JS refresh function on the parent page using GetPostBackBackEventReference on a hidden button.